# Books to understand Szemeredi's regularity lemma?

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

I want to understand the Szemeredi theorem and read on the thoery relating to it. Which books should I pick up to do this? Regards

Comment: Terry Tao has presented a pretty good primer (along with pointers to various others) at http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2012/03/23/some-ingredients-in-szemeredis-proof-of-szemeredis-theorem/

Comment: I think that you can read from the book titled "Additive combinatorics" authored by prof. Tao and Vu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not comlpetely clear to me in that I do not know if it asks maily/only about Szemerédi's Regularity Lemma (title) or at least also about Szemerédi's Theorem on arithmetic progressions (body), which are quite different things. 
(The former being somehow considered as a tool for the latter, and also it or variants of it can be used in this way, but historically this is not so clear; ideed Szemerédi says the regularity lemma has nothing much to do with the theorem, see an [interview with Szemerédi](http://www.ams.org/notices/201302/rnoti-p221.pdf), page 226, 2nd column at the start.) 
That being said:

For the *regularity lemma* there are already several references given, I will add another graph theory book that contains it:

> Bondy and Murty, Graph Theory (Springer, Graduate Text in Mathematics 244)

For *Szemerédi's Theorem* I would receommend

> Tao and Vu, Additive Combinatorics (CUP)

This book contains in one of the last sections, I think the penultimate, a proof of it, and the preceeding section contains a proof of the special case progressions of lengt three.

Answer (score 1):

One of the major (classical) ingredients is the Szemeredi Regularity Lemma, which in itself is a really bizarre concept when you first come across it. On this subject, my favorite quick reference is:

http://www.ti.inf.ethz.ch/ew/lehre/GA10/lec-regularity-new-nopause.pdf

There's also Lovasz and Szegedy's "Szemeredi's Lemma for the Analyst:"

http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~matousek/cla/lovasz-szegedy-continuousregularity.pdf

Also, in addition to Steven Stadnicki's reference, Tao also has the following set of notes:

http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/04/26/szemeredis-regularity-lemma-via-random-partitions/

Comment: Thanks, any books? I can't understand the pdf's you gave me too well. I only know linear algebra, calculus, and some basic combinatorics.(i'm in high school)

Answer (score 1):

The text *Modern Graph Theory* by Bollobas contains a chapter on extremal problems and Szemeredi's regularity lemma.